# iOS Content Blocker - Is having a long JSON file a bad thing?

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, ios9

I'm creating an iOS Ad Blocker, but I'm a bit confused. If I have a long JSON Array (around 64,00 lines) in Xcode is that a bad thing (will it have any affect on battery life or performance) or is it fine?

Comment: No way an app can handle way more data than that.. If you are worried try implement pagination.

Comment: @iphonic I'm sorry, I think you misunderstood. In my Safari Content Blocker, the JSON Rule Array is around 64,000 do you think that will be an issue?

Comment: How big a data structure per rule?